# Cant access the site after activating the wordpress seo plugin

Tags: plugins, wordpress

I have installed the wordpress seo (yoast) plugin on my wordpress site, but if i am activating the plugin it breaks the site. I can access the backend (dashboard) but nothing is visible on front end. It's showing an error message

"The page isn't redirecting properly

Firefox has detected that the server is redirecting the request for this address in a way that will never complete.

```
This problem can sometimes be caused by disabling or refusing to accept cookies."
```

I have already gone through the plugin support but couldn't find anything related to this.

Please provide any solution to resolve the issue.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

There might many causes of breaking site after activating plugin. In your case, may be the reason is memory limit. Please try to add support for more limit. You can use **WP_MAX_MEMORY_LIMIT** to increase it.

You can debug the site using WP_DEBUG in wp-config.php, set it true you will get all the warnings and fatal errors to check the main cause of break.

Answer (score 0):

I Request you to enable debug the site using WP_DEBUG in wp-config.php, set it true you will get all the warnings and fatal errors to check the main cause of break. as mentioned above by @Trimantra Software Solutic.

Go to wp-config.php and find `define('WP_DEBUG', false);` replace with below

```
define('WP_DEBUG', true);
```

After then you will find the error !